# How to compute overlap between nearly parallel two line segments

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry

I have equally oriented (but not exactly parallel) 2D line segments. I want to find out a line segment which is given maximum overlap with a given line segment. 
I think scalars can be used to compute this effectively, but my geometry is too poor to figure out this.
for example, in the below figure; dark line is assumed as the given line and red highlighted line segment is given the maximum coverage (or longest overlap, not sure whether my terminology is correct) when compared to other line segments.

> My objective is to find the best line which represents the dark line
>   from the other line segment sets.

what i want to find is any line which has maximum coverage to a given line. that mean, i want to avoid line segments whose starts and ends are out of the ends of the given line segment. also, when  many lines give their maximum coverage for the given line, then i want to avoid shorter line and need a long one. `idea is to find another line which we can consider instead of that given line segment`

helps are highly appreciated as later i want to implement this in programming environment.
thanks

example 1
[image: example]

[image]
example2

to say what i meant 'coverage', i will say
in above figure: the projected blue line completely lay within the dark black line. but it is too short. But, large portion of the red line (projected line) lay within the black line though some part of the red line go out. green line is completely out of the black line. so, i can say red line give maximum coverage with black line..(does my idea correct?)

Comment: I have trouble understanding this: *I want to find out a line segment which is given maximum overlap with a given line segment.*  I thought you're given *two* or more line segments?  and what does *maximum overlap* mean?

Comment: Mathematically, in an Euclidian plane, segment have at most one intersection if they are not parallel. Could you please define more clearly what your problem is? Do you want to know given two segments how many pixels will overlap when displayed on screen? If so, a segment rendering algorithm like Bresenham could probably be used to at least get a brute force answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as "nearly parallel". Two lines are either parallel to each other or they are not.

Comment: @thang: sorry, i have added an example figure. may be i am not using correct vocabulary.

Comment: actually you can define *parallel-ness* to be the absolute value of the projection the normalized direction vector of one segment into that of the other.  this would be 1 for parallel, 0 for perpendicular, and somewhere in between otherwise.

Comment: @Sylvain Defresne: yes i want sth like that, but i dont have raster data. i am having vector data and i know only the end point coordinates of each line segment.

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap ratio"? Can you give a precise definition of this? In order to solve a problem, you need to have a clear understanding of the problem itself to begin with.

Comment: given two line segments (x1,y1)-(x2,y2) and (u1,v1)-(u2,v2).  there is a linear isometric transformation (actually just rotation) A that transforms the segments into (x1',y1')-(x2',y2') and (u1',v1')-(u2',v2') where v1'=v2' (i.e. it makes one of the two line segments horizontal).  wlog assume x1'<x2' and u1'<u2'.  overlap is defined as max(0, min(u2',x2')-max(u1',x1'))?  is that about right?

Comment: @Code-Guru: i am not sure overlap ratio is relevant for me. but what i want to find is any line which has maximum coverage to a given line. that mean, i want to avoid line segments whose starts and ends are out of the ends of given line segment. also, when i have  many lines give their maximum coverage for the given line, then i want avoid shorter line and need a long one. idea is to find another line which we can consider instead of that given line segment.

Comment: What does "maximum coverage" mean? To start with, you need to define how you measure "coverage". Perhaps you can start with giving an example with only two line segments.

Comment: @Code-Guru he doesn't know exactly... he just has some intuition and it's illustrated in the example.  i suspect is what i defined.

Comment: @Code-Guru: i have given an example to say what i mean 'coverage'. hope you can understand now. thanks

Comment: @thang: i have given an example to say what i mean 'coverage'. hope you can understand now. thanks

Comment: @niro Thanks for the extra description. What you want is much clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Project ends of a candidate segment onto the target segment.
2. Calculate distance between projections.
3. [optionally] Multiply by cos of angle between the segments.

Note about #1: in this context projection on a segment means the closest point lying on that segment. One of ways is:

- project a point on infinite line going through the segment
- if the projection is inside of the segment - take it
- if the projection is outside of the segment - take the closest segment end

Comment: when one end of the candidate segment go out of the target then what shall i do? what does ur 3rd criteria try to measure..(Sorry, i am poor in math) example formula also welcome

Comment: thanks, now i bit got the logic. still I am confused with your this point"[optionally] Multiply by cos of angle between the segments.".. by this, what do you going to measure. like to learn.

Comment: If you want to take into account similarity of directions, multiplication by cosine is one of way to do this. If you need only length of overlapping, no need for the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your question are on graphics processing or computational functions.

But for graphics, this question belongs to computer vision subject, what you want is maybe the [Hough Line Transform algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).

However, if you question is simpler than this, what you want maybe the [SAD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences)

Comment: i think that he already has a list of segment coordinates.  the image is just for illustration only.

Comment: @tomriddle_1234: yes i have all the line segments.. what i a trying to   do is to get most equal line to a given line segment